# Value Converters and WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, dependency-properties

I have a datagrid in wpf, my cell is

```
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding  Value, Converter={StaticResource BinaryGridConverter}, ConverterParameter=1 }"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Everything works fine, the only concern is the converter does not fire on selected cells. My problem will make more sense with the screenshot of my grid,

when i right click on any cell a context menu appear, on allow it will turn the cell green and on disallow it will turn the cell red through the converter.

i have a button, upon click i need to bring the grid back to its original position, through the binding with the dependencyproperty. The issue is when i change the property value the converter does not fire for every cell, it fires for only those cells that are not modified by me.

Comment: Have you tried the DataGridTemplateColumn class? Often it works better than the textcolumn class.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using that should trigger the converter to re-evaluate it's value, but doesn't?

Comment: Hi Rachel, I updated my code that trigger the converter, when i update the value of day.value, my converter fires

Comment: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding  Value, Converter={StaticResource BinaryGridConverter}, ConverterParameter=1 }"/>`.  Please post the relevant code which contains the `Value` property which the Binding is set to (i.e. `Value="{Binding Value, ...`).

Comment: Please check dependency property changed callback, i set the "VALUE" property as {day.Value = BitConverter.ToInt32(newArray.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);}

Comment: Show us what your code for the property "Value" does. Is "Value" also a dependency property? Do you fire the PropertyChanged event for this property correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is when i change the property value the converter does not
>   fire for every cell, it fires for only those cells that are not
>   modified by me.

There is not enough code to be exact, but from your words, it sounds like you set the cell background value manually somewhere in your code, and this way you ***break the binding***.

Double check that you change the cell background through the dependency property using the binding, and not directly.

Comment: You know your answer is too short but to the point, BULLS EYE, thanks a lot, and the bounty is awarded to MichaelS